# Cannot disable autocomplete on chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, autocomplete

I need to avoid that chrome fills some fields with a login data stored on the browser, I tried  adding `autocomplete="off"` and  `autocomplete="unknown-autocomplete-value"` but chrome its still filling these fields, any other way without using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

can you post your code also because in my case its work. Compare between **First Name** and **Last Name** by running code snippet

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="form.php" target="_blank" method="post">
        <label>First Name </label><input type="text" name="FirstName" autocomplete="off"><br><br>
        <label>Last Name </label><input type="text" name="LastName"><br><br>
        <label>Password </label><input type="password" name="password"><br><br>
        <label>Male </label><input type="radio" name="gender"><br>
        <label>Female </label><input type="radio" name="gender"><br>
        <label>Others </label><input type="radio" name="gender"><br>
        <label for=""></label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try to use ```autocomplete="off" ``` in ```<form>``` tag